# Verifying a Limit of a Sequence Using Integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is there an alternative way of verifying this limit using integrals?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^p}{n^{p+1}} = \dfrac{\displaystyle n^p \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{k}{n} \right)^p}{n^{p+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^n \overbrace{\left(\dfrac{k}n \right)^p}^{f(x_k) = x_k^p} \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac1n}_{\Delta_k}$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{k}n \right)^p \cdot \dfrac1n = \lim_{\overset{\Delta x_k \to 0}{n \to \infty}} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \cdot \Delta x_k = \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 x^p dx = \dfrac1{p+1}$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By Riemann sum we have
$$\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^nk^p}{ n^{p+1}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(k/n)^p\to_\infty\int_0^1x^pdx=\frac{1}{p+1}.$$